# Phoenix: Authorizing an authenticated user to join a channel

Tags: authorization, phoenix-framework, channel

With my new HelloPhoenix application, I built a standard basic http user authentication with a register/login form.

Next, I tried channels. It works great. Then, I want authenticated users (and only those who are already authenticated) to be able to join some channels. According to the doc:

> Clients must join a channel to send and receive PubSub events on that
>   channel. Your channels must implement a join/3 callback that
>   authorizes the socket for the given topic. For example, you could
>   check if the user is allowed to join that particular room.

That sounds great, but I wonder what would be the most efficient way. I thought of returning a token (that is associated with the user's model) upon authentication, so the token is passed back to the WebSocket. The join/3 callback could verify that this token matches the one in the model.

Is it the most efficient way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found my answer. [`Phoenix.Token`](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html) is perfect for what I'm trying to achieve.